# Which Linux system calls should I use to read raw characters from stdin?

Tags: node.js, assembly, x86, readline, tty

I'm trying to port my [`stdrepl`](https://github.com/aaditmshah/stdrepl) library to FASM for learning purposes. I know that the GNU readline library already does what I'm trying to do, but I want to learn how to write non-trivial programs in assembly.

In node.js I can easily create a tty by writing:

```
var stdin = process.stdin;
stdin.setEncoding("utf8");
stdin.setRawMode(true);
stdin.resume();
```

How do I achieve the same results in pure assembly. I tried reading one byte from `stdin` at a time in a loop as follows, but it doesn't return the byte right after I hit a key:

```
oct db ?

mov eax, 3
xor ebx, ebx
mov ecx, oct
mov edx, 1
```

Note that the data definition `oct` is not a part of the loop, so please don't smite me for that. I know how to structure an assembly program.

Comment: It is possible to configure stdin such that `sys_read` returns a single key. I have some rudimentary code to do this, but it isn't very good. Certain "signals" will mess it up. (suspending a program with ctrl-d and restoring it with `fg`, or resizing a window in an xterm, for example). I think to do it "right", you'd have to hook signals (which is beyond my current skills). This may be what `setRawMode` does(?). What do you need to do that a simple `sys_read` won't do?

Comment: @FrankKotler - I'm trying to write an interactive echo shell in assembly. The user inputs a line of text and it's echoed back to him. However I want to allow the user to be able to move forward, back, scroll through the history, etc. The way I do it in node.js is that I capture all the keypress events and handle each one separately. I have no idea how to do the same thing in pure assembly using Linux system calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay (I really should "register" here - that'll get me "notifications", right?). As I said, it's rudimentary and imperfect. Some of the "usual" stuff may be defined elsewhere, but I think you can figure out how to get it to assemble. Just call it - no parameters - and the key is returned in `al`. Hope it's some use to you!

```
;-----------------------------
; ioctl subfunctions
%define TCGETS      0x5401 ; tty-"magic"
%define TCSETS      0x5402

; flags for 'em
%define ICANON  2   ;.Do erase and kill processing.
%define ECHO    8   ;.Enable echo.


    struc termios
    alignb 4
    .c_iflag:   resd 1  ; input mode flags
    .c_oflag:   resd 1  ; output mode flags
    .c_cflag:   resd 1  ; control mode flags
    .c_lflag:   resd 1  ; local mode flags
    .c_line:    resb 1  ; line discipline
    .c_cc:      resb 19 ; control characters
    endstruc
 ;---------------------------------

getc:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    sub esp, termios_size     ; make a place for current kbd mode

    push edx
    push ecx
    push ebx

    mov eax, __NR_ioctl        ; get current mode
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, TCGETS
    lea edx, [ebp - termios_size]
    int 80h

                              ; monkey with it
    and dword [ebp - termios_size +  termios.c_lflag], ~(ICANON | ECHO)

    mov eax, __NR_ioctl
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, TCSETS
    lea edx, [ebp - termios_size]
    int 80h

    xor eax, eax
    push eax         ; this is the buffer to read into

    mov eax, __NR_read
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, esp     ; character goes on the stack
    mov edx, 1       ; just one
    int 80h          ; do it

                     ; restore normal kbd mode
    or dword [ebp - termios_size + termios.c_lflag], ICANON | ECHO

    mov eax, __NR_ioctl  
    mov ebx, STDIN
    mov ecx, TCSETS
    lea edx, [ebp - termios_size]
    int 80h

    pop eax          ; get character into al

    pop ebx          ; restore caller's regs
    pop ecx
    pop edx

    mov esp, ebp     ; leave
    pop ebp
    ret
;-------------------------
```