# How to ignore enter-key NASM win32

Tags: string, assembly, input, nasm

I need to ignore the enter on input to further compare the input string with other strings.
Bellow fragment of code input and output

```
;get output handle
    push dword STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [hstdout],eax
    mov eax, 1000h


    ;get input handle
    push dword STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [hstdin],eax

    ;Read
    push 0
    push actlen2 ;Pointer to a DWORD for number of characters read to be returned
    push 11
    push string
    push dword [hstdin]
    call ReadConsoleA

    ;Write
    push 0
    push actlen
    push 11
    push string
    push dword [hstdout]
    call WriteFile
```

String has newline
[Image](https://prnt.sc/12l1570)

Comment: You have the length of the input, so check if the last character is a newline.  If it is, overwrite it with a `0`.  (Or just do that unconditionally, assuming that it is a newline.  Or CR LF if this environment gives you a 2-byte newline sequence on input.)  Like in [How do I ignore line breaks in input using NASM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18780927) which uses Linux system calls; same idea for your WinAPI calls.

Comment: Thanks for help, I figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out 
I just wrote the code that removes 0x0d and 0x0a from the string

```
    mov ecx,11; str len(and num of loop iterations)
    mov eax,string
    jmp ignore_enter
change_byte:
    mov bl,0
    mov byte[eax+ecx],bl;change byte to 0
ignore_enter:
    cmp byte[eax+ecx], 0x0a; compare ecx byte of string with 0x0a
    je change_byte; if equal change_byte
    cmp byte[eax+ecx], 0x0D; compare ecx byte of string with 0x0d
    je change_byte; if equal change_byte
    loop ignore_enter
```

Comment: im noob, mb its stupid solution but it works